# Can't upload to FTP server through SOCKS proxy

Tags: ftp, upload, socks-proxy

This question is somewhat of an extension of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/426308/tunneling-ftp-connection).

My final intention is to be able to upload files to the ftp server in question.

I have FileZilla connecting through a SOCKS proxy created by PuTTY on port 9090 in order to mask my IP address so that I may connect to my work FTP server which will only accept connections from local IP's. PuTTY is ssh'ing to a machine at my work and FileZilla is set to use the local proxy (located at 127.0.0.1:9090) to connect to my work FTP server.

This works successfully, as I am able to connect, get directory listings, download files, and perform several file actions (I've renamed a file, moved a file, deleted a file..etc). However, I am unable to UPLOAD anything. The log appears to show everything going fine then the connection simply times out and the transfer fails.

Note* The server generally (though not always) creates the file I am intending to upload with no data inside it. The personnel.html file I show trying to upload below was created on the server, however FileZilla shows it as having a size of 0B and when I download (or view it online) it is completely blank.

Below I have included the log of FileZilla attempting to upload personnel.html to the FTP server. I have obscured any personally identifiable information.

Status: Connecting to xxx.xxx.10.2 through proxy

Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9090...

Status: Connection with proxy established, performing handshake...

Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...

Response: 220 BulletProof FTP Server ready ...

Command: USER xxxx

Response: 331 Password required for xxxx.

Command: PASS ****

Response: 230 User xxxx logged in.

Status: Connected

Status: Starting upload of C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\prrc\personnel.html

Command: CWD /research_groups/reservoir_sweep_improvement/pages

Response: 250 CWD command successful. "/research_groups/reservoir_sweep_improvement/pages" is current directory.

Status: Retrieving directory listing...

Command: TYPE I

Response: 200 Type set to I.

Command: PASV

Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (xxx,xxx,10,2,128,175)

Command: LIST

Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9090...

Status: Connection with proxy established, performing handshake...

Response: 150 Data connection accepted from xxx.xxx.2.218:39774; transfer starting.

Response: 226 Transfer ok

Command: TYPE A

Response: 200 Type set to A.

Command: PASV

Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (xxx,xxx,10,2,206,73)

Command: STOR personnel.html

Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9090...

Status: Connection with proxy established, performing handshake...

Response: 150 Data connection accepted from xxx.xxx.2.218:58526; transfer starting for personnel.html.

Error: Connection timed out

Error: File transfer failed

**Thanks for any help in advance!!**

Comment: Do you actually have write permissions to upload file in that location? Do you have access to the server to see logs from its end? Have you considered trying another ftp client just to make sure it's not something goofy with filezilla?

Comment: I don't have access to the server for now. I will when I get back to work, but then this workaround won't be needed anymore. 
I was thinking something similar that I may not have write permissions. however, there is only a single ftp user account on the server, and it has had write permissions when I try to upload from a  work machine.
Thats a good suggestion, I'll find another ftp client and give it a try to rule out FileZilla as the problem.

Comment: There's something else I just thought of. To eliminate some more variables, since you are SSH'ing into some server on your work network, have you tried to FTP directly from that server? If upload won't work even from that machine, then you'll know it's not a problem with your proxy or FTP client. Alternatively, if it'll work, then you'll know to look into your local system.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Mxx!! I can't believe I didn't think of simply using a different ftp client.

Turns out it was simply something freeky going on with FileZilla and once I started using SmartFTP instead, it worked perfectly.

I really appreciate it! :)