# Follow up to SSH access to office host behind NAT router

Tags: networking, ssh

I have a problem similar to the already posted  [SSH access to office host behind NAT router](https://superuser.com/questions/277218/ssh-access-to-office-host-behind-nat-router) to access from a homepc an OfficePc using a server with no root access the given solution was:

```
youatwork@officepc$ autossh -R 12345:localhost:22 notroot@serverpc
```

Later:

```
you@homepc$ autossh -L 23456:localhost:12345 notroot@serverpc

you@homepc$ ssh youatwork@localhost -p 23456
```

Provided by @piskvor That works nicely, but I have one problem if the officepc resets because a power cut I can't connect any more to officepc I don't know if the solution provided by @Velmont will work, thanks!

Comment: You need something to restart the autossh from your office PC. That answer by Velmont should work - but you need to put it somewhere it gets autostarted (be it crontab, rc.local, .profile or .autostart)

Comment: Thanks! I used upstart as described here http://serverfault.com/questions/224432/using-upstart-to-manage-autossh-reverse-tunnel